# How can I move MainActivity to activity package created by User?

Tags: android-studio

When we create a new project in Android Studio, by default, MainActivity will be created. Now I created a new package, called "activity". Now I cut and paste MainActivity to activity package, but that all package is coming downside. You'll get to know what I'm asking once you'll try yourself in Android studio.

Current image:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HWNZwgMe6tO-_JrmPHVqr69iXxKEGyoG

But, I want below output:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UnpVmnZEEJbs_Af-QZUW2H0hWBlBkeoV

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle this behaviour using the "Flatten Packages" setting under the settings listed at the top of the file browser in android studio.

Image for reference:
[image]

Comment: Nope. I know that. Without flatten packages, it is showing.

Comment: @DipaliSingh hmm, not too sure than sorry, that was my only guess